# Will changing an HDD in a laptop invalidate my Windows Authenticity?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I have a Samsung laptop with a failing HDD. The laptop came with an original copy of Windows 8. I wish to replace the HDD with a purchased SSD.

I created a Recovery Drive (on a 8GB DoK) - using the "Create recovery drive" utility (that is a part of the Windows OS AFAIK).

I obviously wish to install the OS on the empty SSD, and have a legal copy of Windows on it. I have the CD-KEY and Product-ID (I used ProduKey to extract it). Should there be any problems with that? Will everything just "work" as it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have any issues with the windows key. The only time you would run into issues is if you swapped the motherboard on the computer. You should be able to activate online without issue, but if you do have problems with online activation, use phone activation. Using a different hard drive does not affect the validity of your license.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

As long as you keep the license key, you are fine.

Comment: AFAIK, that's just the product ID, not the product key. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/four-places-find-windows-8-product-key/

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing that out.